A severely ill boy is in a coma because he is trapped in a "parallel" world
The plot evolves around a boy who is severely ill and can't get out of his bed. Their parents try everything so as to get the boy to wake up from this sort of 'coma'. It turns out that it is no ordinary disease, in fact, the invalid is actually trapped outside of its body because it is currently being occupied by another spirit. The father after being put into trance travels to this parallel world in order to bring his son back from this trauma and until the very end you are convinced he was able to do exactly that. In the end, the family takes a photograph as they are united again. In the photograph the aura of an old woman is visible thus representing that the soul that possessed the son is now in hold of the parent. The photographer after realizing what had occurred is chocked to death by the spirit which then turns around to where the remaining of his family went.

That would be Insidious, from Wikipedia: 

The story centers on a couple whose son inexplicably enters a comatose state and becomes a vessel for ghosts in an astral dimension.


I would highly recommend that the OP watches its sequel as well. Insidious Chapter 2. One of the rare occurrences where the sequel is better

Plus Conjuring, cause they are related, and the latest one is purely amazing IMHO.
